Is it possible to obtain the aapt2 binary file built for the arm64 architecture?
I was trying various methods to use apktool on my Android-based server.
My Android server runs on an arm64 architecture, but when I extracted the aapt2 binary file required for APK building from apktool, I found out it was built for x86_64. As a result, it doesn't run on my arm64-based server.
After exploring different resources, including GPT, I realized that while the same aapt2 binary file works, I need one built specifically for arm64.
I came across these links:
https://github.com/JonForShort/android-tools/tree/master/build/android-9.0.0_r33/aapt2/arm64-v8a/bin
https://github.com/JonForShort/android-tools/tree/master/build/android-11.0.0_r33/aapt2/arm64-v8a/bin
These contain aapt2 files built for arm64, which seem like a perfect match. However, I need a more recent version than the ones available in those repositories.
The reason I need the latest version is that I have to use the --no-compile-sdk-metadata option. This option exists in the aapt2 binary currently embedded in apktool (x86_64), but it's missing in the versions provided in the above links.
How can I obtain the latest version of the aapt2 binary built for arm64?
